# ASP POST ActionResult recieves a 0 instead of a provided ID value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Well, hello everyone.

I have a short ASP .NET MVC5 question. I have to pass a value from a ViewBag in the View method with a POST action result.

**Create Method View Trigger**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add TestCase", "Create", "TestPlanTestCases", new { id = Model.TestPlan.ID }, null)
```

**Controller Create GET method**

```
    public ActionResult Create(int id)
    {
        var testPlanFind = _db.TestPlan.Find(id);
        ViewBag.TestPlanID = testPlanFind;
        ViewBag.TestCaseID = new SelectList(_db.TestCase,"ID", "Name")
        return View();
    }
```

**Create View, related DIV:**

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TestPlanID, "TestPlanID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.ViewBag.TestPlanID.Name
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TestPlanID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
```

**Controller Create POST method**

```
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "TestPlanID,TestCaseID")] TestPlanTestCases testPlanTestCases)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.TestPlanTestCases.Add(testPlanTestCases);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", "TestPlans", new {id = testPlanTestCases.TestPlanID});
        }
        ViewBag.TestCaseID = new SelectList(_db.TestCase, "ID", "Name", testPlanTestCases.TestCaseID);
        ViewBag.TestPlanID = new SelectList(_db.TestPlan, "ID", "Name", testPlanTestCases.TestPlanID);
        return View(testPlanTestCases);
```

So, my problem is, when the POST method is being called, the method always receives TestPlanID = 0 and TestCaseID = (ID of the chosen test case). I've used the same workaround for a different controller that has similar functionality and it works perfectly fine, but for some reason, when it comes to setting a predefined value such as TestPlanID it is automatically being set to 0, not even a null. The GET method works fine and passes the right ID, but when it comes down to the POST method, something goes wrong.

[image: Result of Create GET method in View]
[image: Debug: Values of TestPlanID and TestCaseID]

I hope I have provided enough information for you to understand the issue.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `TempData["TestPlanID"] instead of `ViewBag`

Comment: @viveknuna I tried changing the ViewBag to a TempData, but it didn't do much. 
`TempData["TestPlanID"] = testPlanFind.Name`, but the thing is, now it just sends temporary string data. So, the result for the View is the same, be it:
`@Html.ViewBag.TestPlanID.Name` or `@TempData["TestPlanID"]`. But with a ViewBag, I can pass more information rather than just a string(and i do not intend on sending the entire testPlanFind instance to the View), because `ViewBag.TestPlanID` is an instance of an object. Then I can choose what is used by the View and the POST method.

Comment: It seems like that you miss the form element, e.g. input / select / checkbox. The GET method could work is because you add an URL link with query string, your Action can identify that is a HTTP GET request. However, POST need to send a form from client to your server. I notice that you have a form class, so you need to add a submit button and create an input element to store your data, then submit your form data. After doing this, your Action with POST method can receive the data correctly.

Comment: @陳品翰 You mean adding some sort of input to the div where the ViewBag is located? It is actually a good idea I should try out. Overall, the div is located in a Form and it works the same way in a similar function without any additional input. I am going to try to add an input element to the view and hope for the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I've finally solved it, maybe not the best solution, but it works.

A dev friend of mine suggested parsing the URL to get the ID in the POST method. So I've decided to add 3 additional lines of code to the controller, first one to parse the URL for ID value, second to convert the string to Int32, and then assign the result value to the testPlanTestCases.TestPlan.

Updated Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "TestCaseID")] TestPlanTestCases testPlanTestCases)
{
    var testPlanId = RouteData.Values["id"];
    testPlanId = Convert.ToInt32(testPlanId);
    testPlanTestCases.TestPlanID = (int) testPlanId;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.TestPlanTestCases.Add(testPlanTestCases);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", "TestPlans", new {id = testPlanTestCases.TestPlanID});
    }
    ViewBag.TestCaseID = new SelectList(_db.TestCase, "ID", "Name", testPlanTestCases.TestCaseID);
    ViewBag.TestPlanID = new SelectList(_db.TestPlan, "ID", "Name", testPlanTestCases.TestPlanID);
    return View(testPlanTestCases);
```